# Renentrant tryLock() not locking in multi threaded enviroment

Tags: java, reentrantlock

This is regarding `tryLock()` method in re entrant locks. I am running the below sample code. I understand that this code will run into a deadlock.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReentrantLock rl=new ReentrantLock();
        S t1=new S(rl);
        S t2=new S(rl);
        Thread t=new Thread(t1);
        Thread u=new Thread(t2);
        t.start();
        u.start();
    }
}
class S extends Thread{
    ReentrantLock rl;
    S(ReentrantLock r){
        rl=r;
    }
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Entry--");
        rl.tryLock();
        System.out.println("locked1 "+rl.getHoldCount()+" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        rl.lock();
        System.out.println("locked2 "+rl.getHoldCount()+" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        rl.unlock();
        System.out.println("unlocked "+rl.getHoldCount()+" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

But here my question is that why the statement after the `rl.tryLock()` statement is running for the second thread also. Output is coming as

```
Entry--
Entry--
locked1 0 Thread-3
locked1 1 Thread-2
locked2 2 Thread-2
unlocked 1 Thread-2
```

I don't think this line should ever have been printed

```
"locked2 2 Thread-2"
```

Comment: Why should it never have been printed? Your `tryLock` will succeed for one of the threads. `ReentrantLock` is reentrant so `lock` will also succeed for that thread. After that, the hold count will be 2.

Comment: You will have deadlock situation when using 2 locks and 2 threads waiting on each lock to be unlocked by each other. In your case Thread-2 locks on `rl` and Thread-3 waits on `r1` at the `rl.lock()` line forever after getting false from `rl.tryLock();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like `lock`, `tryLock` must also be paired with an `unlock` IF it returns `true`. When using `tryLock` you MUST check the return value and unlock if it was locked, because otherwise it will never be fully unlocked.

When it prints the following sequence occurs: [Note this is a possible sequence, between 5 and 8 can be re-arranged because multiple threads are involved and it'll still be correct]

1. [Thread-2] `System.out.println("Entry--");`
2. [Thread-3] `System.out.println("Entry--");`
3. [Thread-2] `rl.tryLock();` [r1 now locked to Thread-2, count=1]
4. [Thread-3] `rl.tryLock();` [r1 already locked, returns false]
5. [Thread-3] `System.out.println("locked1 "+rl.getHoldCount()+" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());` [r1 not held, count is thus 0]
6. [Thread-2] `System.out.println("locked1 "+rl.getHoldCount()+" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());` [r1 held, count=1]
7. [Thread-3] `rl.lock();` [r1 already locked, blocks]
8. [Thread-2] `r1.lock();` [r1 held, count=2]
9. [Thread-2] `System.out.println("locked2 "+rl.getHoldCount()+" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());`
10. [Thread-2] `rl.unlock();` [r1 held, count=1]
11. [Thread-2] `System.out.println("unlocked "+rl.getHoldCount()+" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());`

The line `"locked2 2 Thread-2"` is printed because a re-entrant lock can be locked more than once **if locked by the holder**. So both `tryLock` and `lock` succeed, but you unlock only one of them, so the other thread blocks forever.